# No authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("Bearer",...)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, jwt

I am bale to get generated token but not able to use it for Authorized action method, I am facing issue while accessing Authorized controller method with JWT generated token, please let me know any helpful solution to resolve this issue.
enter image description here

***Actual Issue image:***
[image]

***Token is getting generated:***
[image]

***Following code is in appsetting.json file***

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "JWTConfig": {
    "Key": "Yh2k7QSu4l8CZg5p6X3Pna9L0Miy4D3Bvt0JVr87UcOj69Kqw5R2Nmf4FWs03Hdx",
    "Issuer": "JWTAuthenticationServer",
    "Audience": "JWTServicePostmanClient",
    "Subject": "JWTServiceAccessToken"
  }
}
```

***Following code is in Startup.cs file:***

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAuthentication(a=>
            {
                a.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                a.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(opts =>
            {
                opts.SaveToken = true;
                opts.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                opts.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    SaveSigninToken = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = configuration["JWTConfig:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = configuration["JWTConfig:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["JWTConfig:key"]))
                };
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("Bearer", "RPS");
                defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
            });

        }

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

***Following code is in Controller***

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

***Following code is in Controller to generate token***

```
[HttpPost("VerifyUserGenerateTocken")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> VerifyUserGenerateTocken(UserLoginDetail loginUser)
        {
            UserLoginDetail userLoginDetail = new UserLoginDetail();
            JWTDetail jWTDetail = new JWTDetail()
            {
                UserName=  loginUser.UserName,
                Password =  loginUser.Password
            };
            if(jWTDetail == null)
            {
                jWTDetail.LoginMessage = "Empty credential enterd";
                return (IActionResult)jWTDetail;
            }
            using (var conn = new OTTPlatformContext())
            {
                userLoginDetail = await conn.UserLoginDetails.Where(a => 
                    a.UserName == jWTDetail.UserName &&
                    a.Password == jWTDetail.Password
                    ).FirstAsync();

                if (userLoginDetail != null)
                {
                    jWTDetail.AccessToken = GetTocken(jWTDetail);
                    jWTDetail.LoginMessage = "Login Success";
                    return Ok(jWTDetail);
                }
                else
                {
                   jWTDetail.LoginMessage = "No Data Posted";
                    return BadRequest(jWTDetail);
                }
            }
        }
        private string GetTocken(JWTDetail loginUser)
        {

            var claims = new[] {
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, _configuration["JWTConfig:Subject"]),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()),
                        new Claim("UserName", loginUser.UserName),
                        new Claim("UserPassword", loginUser.Password)
                    };


            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["JWTConfig:Key"]));
            var signIn = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                            _configuration["JWTConfig:Issuer"],
                            _configuration["JWTConfig:Audience"],
                            claims,
                            expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
                            signingCredentials: signIn);


            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }
```

Comment: Is `ConfigureServices` called at startup?

Comment: -Yes, It is in startup file, I will correct Ask statement.